# 64 bit version of Java 1.4.2 for Windows?

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit

Is there a 64 bit version of Java 1.4.2 for Windows?

I need this because of a BEA WebLogic 8.1 application that runs out of memory all the time.

**UPDATE:** 
As [Tom Hawtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) pointed out there are licensing problems with the Sun 64 bit version I suggested in my own answer. Just out of curiosity:
**If you know a version which is available under more liberal terms, please let me know.**

**UPDATE:**
No, I don't want to discuss why the application needs so much memory.
No, I don't want to discuss why we are still running BEA 8.1.
I accept your condolences though.

Comment: If it's available from Sun, it'll be in the archive area. http://java.sun.com/products/archive/ I suggest upgrading to a version that isn't in, or about to hit the end of, its End Of Service Life period (i.e. Java SE 6).

Comment: WebLogic 8.1 was from... when?  2003?  "I'm not in the position to question..." is a cop out.  They are out of support. Any 100k employee company that is running "enterprise" software with no support and with known, unfixable security bugs in the underlying JVM, deserves to be questioned.

Comment: I have understood that the BEA situation is exactly why the Business version of Java 1.4 is available from Sun.  Pay up :)

Comment: @Cheeso: I know that, you know that, but whining doesn't help me here and now to get that piece of software running;-)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Ah, here it starts to get interesting. You mean I could buy a 64 bit version of Java 1.4. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IBM had a 1.4.2 64bit JDK shipped with DB2 8.1

Comment: You will not be able to use this JVM with any thing else other than the product it shipped with. IBM license terms very clear on this.

Answer (score 3):

So, you have no support on the App Server, no supported JVM to run it with... You're not in a nice place :).

However, if you app is running out of memory and you've squeezed every ounce of performance you could, you could always deploy your app in a cluster

This way, you could spread out the memory load.

Answer (score 2):

Oh yes there is. For some reason Sun has just decided to hide it as good as they could.
You can download it from [Sun's SAP site](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/SAPsite/download.html).

It seems to work well with BEA WebLogic 8.1.

**UPDATE:** As Tom Hawtin pointed out:

> This version of the J2SE 1.4.2 SDK is
>   strictly for use by SAP customers
>   along with SAP software products.

**If anyone knows of a version which is available under more liberal terms, please let me know.**

Comment: **This version of the J2SE 1.4.2 SDK is strictly for use by SAP customers along with SAP software products. **

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: Thanks for the comment, I didn't notice that. Updated my question.

Comment: I don't understand why you are not asking BEA/Oracle for the supported 64-bit JVM for WebLogic 8.1.  This is a very short conversation. If they don't have jRockit 1.4.2 for Win64, and they don't have a Sun JVVM 1.4.2 64-bit, then... it's not a supported configuration and you should get up to date.